Синтаксический разбор (3)
1. Я помогу найти тебе подарок.
Как выполнить синтаксический разбор данного предложения? «Помогу найти» — это составное глагольное сказуемое или же сказуемое и дополнение?
2. Я помогу тебе найти подарки.
Будет ли различаться разбор этого предложения? Если да, то почему?
С одной стороны мы можем сказать, что первое действие будет выполняться одним лицом (я помогу), а второе действие — другим (он найдет). Тогда это будет сказуемое + дополнение.
Но ведь можно посмотреть и с другой стороны... (Помогать буду я, искать тоже буду я.)
Update: Вспомнился еще пример.
3. Я позволила себе отдохнуть.
Тоже спорный момент, вроде и первое, и второе действие будет выполнять один субъект, но у нас есть возвратное местоимение «себя». Быть может, одно действие (позволила) направлено на подлежащее «я», а другое действие (отдохнуть) направлено на объект «себя»?
Это составное глагольное сказуемое или сказуемое + дополнение?


Я помогу найти тебе подарок. 2. Я помогу тебе найти подарки.

Как можно решать эту задачу
Распространители (тебе,  подарок) неважны, главное — это структурная схема: Я помогу найти. Чем является инфинитив найти? Если связка имеет модальное значение, то это СГС. Именно на это нужно обратить внимание.
Глагол помочь является модальным? Вероятно да, как и глагол мочь. Но что-то мне не нравится в этой модальности.
Я помогу (что сделать?) найти... А что это значит? Субъект в любом случае будет участвовать в действии вместе с кем-то. Значит это СГС, потому что в инфинитиве и модальном глаголе один субъект действия.
  Не являются составными глагольными сказуемые, выраженные: 
  2)сочетанием простого глагольного сказуемого с 
  инфинитивом, занимающим в предложении **позицию 
  дополнения** в случае разных **субъектов действия** у 
  спрягаемой формы глагола и инфинитива: Все просили её 
  спеть (все просили, а спеть должна она);

Проверим разбор  похожего предложения на учебных сайтах: Я помог ему найти книгу. На двух-трех сайтах выделяют СГС. Значит, все нормально? Но какое-то недовольство все-таки есть.
Тогда проверим модальность. Модальность глагола — это категория в лингвистике, которая обозначает возможность, чью-то способность, вероятность или вынужденность совершения какого-либо действия, но не само действие.  Но помочь — это как раз совершать действия. Сравним: Я могу помочь ему найти книгу. Могу помочь — вот СГС.
А как же учебные сайты?
Это правильно?  Простое глагольное сказуемое.  https://textbot.ru/sintaksicheskiy-razbor
А это неправильно? СГС. https://textovod.com/syntax https://textplus.ru/sintaksicheskiy-razbor
СОРЕВНУЮТСЯ ИИ, надо думать?  А что скажут настоящие лингвисты?
ВЫВОД (мое решение):
Я помогу найти тебе подарок. Я помогу тебе найти подарки.
Это простое глагольное сказуемое, так как помогу не является модальным глаголом.
Я позволила себе отдохнуть. Это фразеология: Я решила (высказала намерение) отдохнуть. Тематика модальных глаголов, поэтому СГС.
КРАТКАЯ ТЕОРИЯ по учебнику Литневской стр. 78
Составное глагольное сказуемое (СГС) имеет следующую структуру: связка + инфинитив. Инфинитив выражает основное лексическое значение сказуемого — называет действие.
Связка выражает грамматическое значение сказуемого, а также дополнительную характеристику действия — указание на его начало, середину или конец (фазисное значение) или возможность, желательность, степень обычности и другие характеристики, описывающие отношение субъекта действия к этому действию (модальное значение).
Фазисное значение выражается:
  глаголами стать, начать (начинать), 
  приняться(приниматься), продолжить (продолжать), перестать 
  (переставать), прекратить (прекращать) и некоторыми 
  другими (чаще всего это синонимы к приведённым словам, 
  характерные для разговорного стиля речи): Я начал / 
  продолжил / закончил читать эту книгу.

Модальное значение может выражаться:
 1) глаголами уметь, мочь, хотеть, желать, стараться, 
 намереваться, осмелиться, отказаться, думать, предпочитать, 
 привыкнуть, любить, ненавидеть, остерегаться и Т. п.
 2) глаголом-связкой быть (в наст. времени в нулевой форме) 
 + краткими прилагательными рад, готов, обязан, должен, 
 намерен, способен, а также наречиями и существительными с 
 модальным значением:
 Я был готов / не прочь / в состоянии подождать.
 Как в приинфинитивной части, так и в позиции инфинитива 
 может быть употреблён фразеологизм:
 Он горит нетерпением участвовать в конференции (= хочет 
 участвовать)
 Он хочет принять участие в конференции (= хочет 
 участвовать).
 Он горит нетерпением принять участие в конференции (= хочет 
 участвовать).


Вот пара примеров инфинитивов-дополнений из хорошей статьи
Вчера мы договорились (о чем?) поехать на дачу. 
За неделю он научился (чему?) кататься на коньках. 
Сестра быстро привыкла (к чему?) ухаживать за больной матерью.

А вот пример зависимости синтаксического разбора от порядка слов:
Спорить с ним бесполезно // Подлежащно-сказуемостное
Бесполезно спорить с ним // Безличное

Теперь по вопросу:
Помогу найти (себе)
Разрешу отдохнуть (себе)

Тут в общем случае разные субъекты действия. Иногда они могут совпадать, но суть от этого не меняется. Второй тест (не использующий разносубъектности) на дополнение/сказуемое можно предложить такой: помогу\разрешу не употребляется с существительными в качестве дополнений, а привык\научился употребляется (привык к нему). Исключение составляет глагол люблю: Я люблю это\Я люблю делать это. Почему-то здесь считается СГС, хотя по логике должно быть дополнение.
А вообще почему бы не считать все инфинитивы-дополнениями? В чем тут конкретные формальные трудности?
